# Laravel 5.3 backend and Vue 2.0 form to create user

Tags: laravel, post, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having trouble authenticating users via Vue 2.0.

In Vue I have a form in which the user enters all his data and submits it via POST to a Laravel (web route) endpoint.

Then the user is created in the UserController method with the supplied data and I'm stuck at this point as I don't manage to authenticate my user after creation and redirecting him to some route (other page).

User creation goes fine...

Can someone explain me rapidly how it should work? (as I understood that I can't redirect from the controller as the data is POSTed via an ajax call).

What's the "right" way to do this as I'm afraid I'm completely mistaken :)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well you get some kind of response anyway, so just redirect user in Vue depending on which response you got from laravel. But I think you want to use laravel passport.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to perform the redirection at the front end script after receiving the response from the controller method.

This is my thought as a possible solution for you:-

1. The authentication can be done in the controller following the creation. The controller method then need to return a JSON response indicating success.

Note: Laravel 5.3 ships with pre-built authentication controllers. RegisterController handles user registration.

2. The Vue script need to process the response i.e. if success, redirect to somewhere or if failed, prompt a message.

Cheers!